# Is it possible to access Azure Virtual Machine local site in Azure web App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-webapps

Can we host website in Azure Virtual Machine and access that in another website which in hosted as Azure web app service?

We have community website which we want to host on azure virtual machine and we want to update/get community website content using web API on website which is hosted as Azure Web App.

So is it possible to access Azure Virtual Machine local site in Azure web App Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to access Azure VM resources from Azure app service.

By default, the inbound and outbound of Azure app services are directly going to the Internet. If the network interface of Azure VM is assigned with a public IP, and the websites in the Azure VM has published to the internet, then you can access that Azure VM website from your app service, just like the normal public websites do.

In addition, if you want to access the Azure VM website from your app service within the Azure virtual network, you can consider [integrating your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). VNet Integration is used only to make outbound calls from your app into your virtual network. The VNet Integration feature behaves differently when it's used with virtual networks in the same region and with virtual networks in other regions. In this scenario, you don't need to assign a public IP to the Azure VM.

For more information about connecting app service to the on-premise resources or the resources in another virtual network, you could refer to [this blog](https://www.petri.com/connect-azure-web-apps-premises).

Let's me know if you need further help.